# Mystery CD Drive

Tags: windows-7, cd-drive

For some reason, I have a mystery CD Drive that appears every time I boot up my computer:

[image]

I've tried disabling my CD drive (E:) from Device Manager, but CD Drive G: remains. The reason I am concerned with this is Windows changed my disk drives on my last startup. This switched D: and G:, so all my programs/file links from D: no longer worked. I want to prevent this from happening, so I'm trying to get rid of this mystery G: drive.

A few facts:

- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- I have one physical DVD RW Drive drive (E:)
- I do have PowerISO installed (which I believe is the CD Drive's icon)

### Any idea what this mystery drive is and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just right click the PowerISO icon in the system tray and there's something like `Emulated Drives => 0`

Comment: Unistall PowerISO to get-rid off this drive (G:) otherwise as @ta.speot.is said make drives =>0 from PowerISO.

Answer (score 4):

It's most likely an emulated drive by PowerISO. Can you right click and eject it? Does it disappear then?

To fix your drive letter issue:

- Open the start menu (or run dialog) and enter **compmgmt.msc**. You should get a single hit, start it. This should oben a new window.
- Doubleclick on **Computer Management** (might be named slightly differently).
- In the new window look on the left panel and find **Disk Management**.
- On the right side, you should see all your drives in the lower part of the window.
- Here you can right click any drive and use the context menu to change the assigned drive letters. You might have to remove some assignment first to free letters for other drives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looked like it was a PowerISO emulated drive, but I couldn't eject it. I did figure out how to get rid of it: http://superuser.com/questions/755424/mystery-cd-drive/755546#answer-755546

Comment: Also, for the letter drive issue, the PowerISO emulated drive didn't show in Disk Management. Just my physical DVD drive. That's where I went first though.

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue. It was an emulated drive from PowerISO. My PowerISO didn't have a system tray icon or an option for "emulated drives" so I poked around a little more and found `Mount  (icon) > Set Number Of Drives > Disable`.

I didn't find this before because I had previously tried `Mount (icon) > Unmound All Drives` and figured if that didn't do it, it probably wasn't PowerISO.

Thanks for all the tips that lead to the answer!